# TFS 2008 erratically showing past builds

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We do use TFS to do automatic build and tests with our checkins.

Today we verified old builds we have done last week. We were seeking one specific : 2010/10/27 (5). For some kind of reason it was not showing when we opened TFS/Project/Builds in visual studio (or the build tab in TFS Web).

Here is a screenshot that shows what we saw:
[image]

(Bigger screenshot here : http://i55.tinypic.com/35lt1z6.png )

For some reason some builds are jumping, tho I can attest that each builds are iterating and on the 27th there was a 5th build.

Is there something that can prevent TFS from showing complete builds history ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the retention policy? It removes builds when there are more then N builds.

Comment: Sounds nice idea but why then would the 26th have the 12, 11 and ... 8 (?!) the 29th would have each one and ... the 27th have only the first 2 ones ?

Comment: The retention policy is on the build status. Was the build you are searching for succeeded?

Comment: It did. But even if it wouldn't why would it be different from 20101028.6 to 20101029.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Date Filter drop down at the upper right corner of your screen shot which is currently set for last 7 days.

Comment: Yep but as you can see for builds around the 27th of october it goes from 20101027.2 to 20101028.6 to 20101029.1 and I can assure you that there were at least 5 builds on the 27th so they should be showing. In TFS if you try to assign a specific build to a work item you can even select the 20101027.5 build, oddly enough it's not here.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound obvious, but if you didn't lock the build, then it's also pretty easy to press delete on it (although hopefully the confirmation dialog would save you).

If the build's drop folder is still in your file system, then pretty much all the information on the build is still safe, even if the build has been dropped from your TFS database.

(The only problem I've seen with TFS (2005/2008/2010) is that even if you delete builds, they still show up in the WorkItem user interface so testers have to try to choose the build name from a nearly infinite list - so of course they type something sort-of-like the build number into the field. Sigh)